# How to return values correctly using withSuccessHandler

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm again having some trouble with google.script.run, this time, I want to retrieve data from a spreadsheet. If you see an error, feel free to write it in the answers.

By the way, here are some bits of the code that I used:

Html Code:

```
alert(GetData(0, 1, 1));

function GetData(Page, GetRow, GetColumn)
  {
    var DataExtracted;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(Data){DataExtracted = Data;}).GetCellValue({PageNum: Page, Row: GetRow, Column: GetColumn});
    return DataExtracted;
  }
```

Gs Code:

```
var Server = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...');
//I'm not writing the Url, because of privacy
var Pages = Server.getSheets();
function GetCellValue(Object)
{
  return Pages[Object.PageNum].getRange(Object.Row, Object.Column).getValue();
}
```

Comment: In `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(call back function name).serverfunctionname()` the withSuccessHandler is the name of the function that the return value from serverfunctionname() will be returned to.  It can also be an anonymous function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<script>
var DataExtracted;
function GetData(Page, GetRow, GetColumn) {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(Data){
       DataExtracted=Data;//DataExtracted is global and available to other functions
       window.alert(Data);
    })
    .GetCellValue({PageNum: Page, Row: GetRow, Column: GetColumn});    
  }
</script>
```

GS:

```
function GetCellValue(Object) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheets()[Object.PageNum];//assuming numbers start at zero
  return sh.getRange(Object.Row, Object.Column).getValue();
}
```

Normally there are atleast a few seconds between calling the server function and calling the withSuccessHandler.  You can use gData in other functions.  It's the value returned from the server function getCellValue();

Comment: Thanks, also, do you know a way to get the data as a variable?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?:                                       
DataExtracted = Data;

Comment: I just changed the name.  The point is that you can pass to other functions by declaring it outside of the functions.

Comment: Oh, ok. By the way, when I alert the variable, It returns an "undefined" value

Comment: Please update your code so that I can see what you're talking about.  And please provide the html so that I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var DataExtracted;
GetData(0, 1, 1);
alert(DataExtracted);
function GetData(Page, GetRow, GetColumn)
  {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(Data){DataExtracted = Data;}).GetCellValue({PageNum: Page, Row: GetRow, Column: GetColumn});
  }
```

Comment: No.  Because you are calling GetData() and alert() before the call back has received the data.  Put the alert inside of the call back.

Comment: Sometime I will wait as much as 30 or 45 second before I get the call back.  That's rare but it does happen sometimes.